# Yii2 Composer and Bower issue

Tags: php, yii2, composer-php, bower

I am facing a problem during Yii2 installation.

I have repository on Bitbucket. Its obvious that after `git clone/fetch/pull` i need to install dependencies. Everything that i am trying to do is always inside newly created `php 7.2.0` Docker image machine (Bitbucket Pipelines). So here is the list of commands that i have:

```
php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
php composer-setup.php
php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"
php composer.phar create-project
```

My `composer.json` file is equals to [one](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-basic/blob/master/composer.json) from [official repository](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-basic).

**The problem** is that `web/assets` directory is lacking of files. It has autogenerated directories and only yii, yii activeForm, captcha, gridView and validation JS files.

As i know `composer-asset-plugin` not used any more. At least no mention in installation guide. But even if i add `php composer.phar global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:^1.4.2"` it won't fix the issue. It looks like bower assets can't be compiled or something like that. Maybe i am wrong. I have no idea why its not working. No results during search too.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Not sure if it is your case but check if you have two directories in `vendor`-path: `bower` and `bower-asset`. If you do not have one, copy (or symlink) existing to missing one.

Comment: @witzawitz First of all I've checked it, `vendor/bower-asset` folder exists and contains files. After installation my script performs `mv vendor/bower-asset vendor/bower` but this is slightly different (and very old) issue that i have and IMO they are not related.
By the way no issues on local Win machine were found (except `bower-asset` folder name but simple renaming fixes it).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For people who facing this issue. I've checked everything once more, it should work but it doesn't. All essential directories have correct rights. Everything is working perfectly except this bower issue. I doublecheck on local PC. Can't reproduce.

However after about 10 takes to fix, it starts working correctly. Maybe it is `yii\web\AssetManager` issue or something, i still don't know, time will show.

### UPD 22.10.2018

You just need to add this code to you cofig file and it will fix this issue.

```
'aliases' => [
    '@bower' => '@vendor/bower-asset',
    '@npm'   => '@vendor/npm-asset'
]
```

It was also added to [application templates](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-basic/blob/master/config/web.php#L10)

Answer (score 0):

Issue come when we are using composer 2. Otherwise we can use fxp/composer-asset-plugin. MihaOo answered for basic app. For people who are using advanced app can use following configuration.

Update common/config/main.php with following config.

```
'aliases' => [
    '@bower' => '@vendor/bower-asset',
    '@npm'   => '@vendor/npm-asset',
],
```

Original config file from yii2 advanced app - [configuration file](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced/blob/master/common/config/main.php)

More information about this - [Yii2 Forum](https://forum.yiiframework.com/t/problems-with-composer-2-and-bower-asset/130825/12)

Complete solution in Asset packagelist -[Asset packagelist](https://asset-packagist.org/site/about)